# Javascript calling action:function

Tags: visualforce, inline-visualforce

I'm trying to adapt logic from [this old post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24175/passing-method-parameters-with-apexactionfunction) by having a javascript function call an **apex:actionFunction** instead of **apex:outputLink**.   Here's my VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="testParam">
<apex:form >
<script type="text/javascript">
    function func1(val) {
      DeleteQuoteLineItem('TEST VALUE from func1');
      alert("func1: "+val);
    }
</script>

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Query" onclick="func1('a')" rerender="content"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:outputLink value="javascript:if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) DeleteQuoteLineItem('TEST VALUE');">
    Del
    </apex:outputLink>

    <apex:actionFunction action="{!DeleteQuoteLineItem}" name="DeleteQuoteLineItem" rerender="content">
        <apex:param name="myParam" value=""/>
    </apex:actionFunction>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The controller is simply:

```
public class testParam {

    public PageReference DeleteQuoteLineItem() {
    string passedParam1 = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myParam');
        system.debug('Delete Quote Line Item with '+passedParam1);
        return null;
    }

}
```

In any case, clicking **apex:outputLink** calls the controller method successfully, but clicking the **apex:commandButton** does not.  I do see my alert fire but the controller method does not seem to be called at all.  Is what I'm trying to do is illegal?

Comment: Scott, I've fixed your code for you. The `` is used for inline code. Prefix each line of block code with four spaces to get it to format as a block, or if you can use Ctrl/Cmd+K after selecting the text, it will automatically indent your code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not cancelling the button's default action, which causes the default form processing to occur (which ultimately re-renders the page). I wouldn't be surprised if this causes some Bad Things to happen. You'll want to prevent the default form processing by returning false:

```
onclick="func1('a');return false;"
```

The link doesn't have a problem, because you're setting the rendered link's href attribute to a JavaScript function, so there's no other library code being called/page being unloaded/etc.

Comment: That worked!  Is this because the page refresh would cancel the call to the controller's method?  Re-reading the docs says if an action is not specified the page simply refreshes.

Comment: That's right. Browsers tend to forcefully terminate all open connections when a page unloads (that's why we have a "before unload" function), so the reload cancels anything that would have been called.